# Firebase create node with email address

Tags: firebase, angularfire

After reading [this blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) about denormalizing data, I'm trying to create a directive to check against already user mail directions, so my model would be something like this:

```
root {
  users{
     userId: 1
     userMail: test@gmail.com
   {
  mails{
     test@gmail.com {
       userId: 1
     }
   {
}
```

So the idea is to check against a reference for the node root/mails but when I try to model this with the firebase forge it doesn't allow me to create a node with the mail. If I put an @ symbol it does not throw any error but nothing happens, only if I take off the @ symbol it will properly add the new node.

Anybody can assist on how to achieve this? did I misunderstood anything from the above article about how to structure my data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following characters are not allowed as key names in Firebase:

```
. (period)
$ (dollar sign)
[ (left square bracket)
] (right square bracket)
# (hash or pound sign)
/ (forward slash)
```

You can escape your email address to the form "user@gmail,com" (replace the "." with a ","), then you should be able to store the data as laid out.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a safer bet to use a Base64 + a little extra security:

- Base64 encode the email address
- Replace / with -

You gain a few advantages

- No need to make up a completely custom serializer for all the characters Anant listed as not allowed
- Easier for the end user to decode since Base64 is pretty universal with the exception of the / swapping

Or if data size isn't a massive concern Base16 (Hex) looks really nice and will always just be letters and numbers.